# appending div inline with table thead th element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to put question mark next to the column name. After searching on the net I found out that I should be using `display: flex` it works great for a single column but when I try to do the same to other columns It start appearing as shown in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fo0shcd/3/) output. What's wrong? How to put icon next to the column then?

```js
$(function() { 
$('table thead tr .col_heading.level0.col2').append("<div data-toggle='tooltip' title='We need your phone number because...'>?</div>")
$('table thead tr .col_heading.level0.col3').append("<div data-toggle='tooltip' title='We need your phone number because...'>?</div>")
});
```

```css
.col_heading.level0.col2 {
position: relative;
  display: flex;
  /* width:40%; */
  
} 

.col_heading.level0.col3 {
position: relative;
  display: flex;
  /* width:40%; */
  
} 
.col_heading.level0.col2 .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
    /* display: inline-block; */

  z-index: 1;
}

.col_heading.level0.col2:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

#T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcd
{
 position:absolute;
    

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcd" >
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="blank level0" ></th>
         <th class="col_heading level0 col0" > a</th>
         <th class="col_heading level0 col1" >b</th>
         <th class="col_heading level0 col2" >c</th>
         <th class="col_heading level0 col3" >d</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdlevel0_row0" class="row_heading level0 row0" > 0
         </th>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow0_col0" class="data row0 col0" >1</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow0_col1" class="data row0 col1" >x</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow0_col2" class="data row0 col2" >0</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow0_col3" class="data row0 col3" >0.0106405</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdlevel0_row1" class="row_heading level0 row1" >1</th>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow1_col0" class="data row1 col0" >2</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow1_col1" class="data row1 col1" >y</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow1_col2" class="data row1 col2" >0</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow1_col3" class="data row1 col3" >0.00423519</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdlevel0_row2" class="row_heading level0 row2" >2</th>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow2_col0" class="data row2 col0" >3</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow2_col1" class="data row2 col1" >z</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow2_col2" class="data row2 col2" >0</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow2_col3" class="data row2 col3" >0.0071003</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @ShafayetHossen I want to add tooltip to a column. So when the user hover on it he/she should be able to see the details.

Comment: https://codepen.io/shafayethossen1991/pen/YzPPaWY?editors=1111 try my codepen link. Ithink it will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put a div directly inside a table but you can put div inside td or th element. You could use display: table-row-group for your div. If we follow the w3 org table reference ,and follow the Permitted Contents section, we can see that the table tags takes tbody (optional) and tr as the only permitted contents.

You can add another tag (b,span,em etc.) into div tag to work properly. Ex:

```
$(function() { 
 $('table thead tr .col_heading.level0.col2').append("<div data-toggle='tooltip' title='We need your phone number because...'><p>?</p></div>")
 $('table thead tr .col_heading.level0.col3').append("<div data-toggle='tooltip' title='We need your phone number because...'><p>?</p></div>")
});
```

Comment: Try this https://codepen.io/shafayethossen1991/pen/YzPPaWY?editors=1111

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() { 
$('table thead tr .col_heading.level0.col2').append("<div data-toggle='tooltip' title='We need your phone number because...'>?</div>")
$('table thead tr .col_heading.level0.col3').append("<div data-toggle='tooltip' title='We need your phone number because...'>?</div>")
});
```

```css
        .col_heading.level0.col2 {/* position: relative; *//* display: flex; *//* width:40%; */} 

.col_heading.level0.col3 {/* position: relative; *//* display: flex; *//* width:40%; */} 
.col_heading.level0.col2 .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
    /* display: inline-block; */

  z-index: 1;
}

.col_heading.level0.col2:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

#T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcd
{
 position:absolute;
 width: 100%;
}

table thead tr div { display:inline-block; }
table thead tr { text-align:left; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcd" >
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="blank level0" ></th>
         <th class="col_heading level0 col0" > a</th>
         <th class="col_heading level0 col1" >b</th>
         <th class="col_heading level0 col2" >c</th>
         <th class="col_heading level0 col3" >d</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdlevel0_row0" class="row_heading level0 row0" > 0
         </th>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow0_col0" class="data row0 col0" >1</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow0_col1" class="data row0 col1" >x</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow0_col2" class="data row0 col2" >0</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow0_col3" class="data row0 col3" >0.0106405</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdlevel0_row1" class="row_heading level0 row1" >1</th>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow1_col0" class="data row1 col0" >2</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow1_col1" class="data row1 col1" >y</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow1_col2" class="data row1 col2" >0</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow1_col3" class="data row1 col3" >0.00423519</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdlevel0_row2" class="row_heading level0 row2" >2</th>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow2_col0" class="data row2 col0" >3</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow2_col1" class="data row2 col1" >z</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow2_col2" class="data row2 col2" >0</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow2_col3" class="data row2 col3" >0.0071003</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

in this issue u can check my code div is a display block item u have to choose another type of element like a span but if u want to have div (it not) u can give it display: inline-block; and some css fix some issues

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() { 
$('table thead tr .col_heading.level0.col2').append("<div data-toggle='tooltip' title='We need your phone number because...'>?</div>")
$('table thead tr .col_heading.level0.col3').append("<div data-toggle='tooltip' title='We need your phone number because...'>?</div>")
});

/* $('<div> , </div>').css("display","inline")
/* $('table thead').append('<tr class="child"><th><td>blahblah</td></th></tr>') */
```

```css
/*↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓*/
.col_heading.level0.col2 {
 
  text-align:left;
} 

.col_heading.level0.col3 {
text-align:left;
  
} 
.col_heading.level0 div{
  display:inline-block;
}

/*↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑*/

.col_heading.level0.col2 .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
    /* display: inline-block; */

  z-index: 1;
}

.col_heading.level0.col2:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

#T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcd
{
 position:absolute;
    

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcd" >
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="blank level0" ></th>
         <th class="col_heading level0 col0" >a</th>
         <th class="col_heading level0 col1" >b</th>
         <th class="col_heading level0 col2" >c</th>
         <th class="col_heading level0 col3" >d</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdlevel0_row0" class="row_heading level0 row0" > 0
         </th>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow0_col0" class="data row0 col0" >1</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow0_col1" class="data row0 col1" >x</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow0_col2" class="data row0 col2" >0</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow0_col3" class="data row0 col3" >0.0106405</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdlevel0_row1" class="row_heading level0 row1" >1</th>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow1_col0" class="data row1 col0" >2</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow1_col1" class="data row1 col1" >y</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow1_col2" class="data row1 col2" >0</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow1_col3" class="data row1 col3" >0.00423519</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdlevel0_row2" class="row_heading level0 row2" >2</th>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow2_col0" class="data row2 col0" >3</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow2_col1" class="data row2 col1" >z</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow2_col2" class="data row2 col2" >0</td>
         <td id="T_3bac276a_15f8_11ea_b73d_475809f3cfcdrow2_col3" class="data row2 col3" >0.0071003</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Do not modify `<th> -> display` in `<table>`